# concurrent access to static methods in java, is synchronization needed?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, static, synchronization

Do different threads accessing method "foo" have their own copy of local variables, or it is needed to make this method synchronized?

```
class X {
   static returnType foo( Object arg) {
      Object localvar;
      // perform some calculation based on localvar and arg.
      // no non-local variable is used i.e: this is a utility method.
      // return something.
   }
}
```

Comment: I can recommend the book "Java Concurrency in Practice" for any further questions you might encounter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need to synchronize that method. The local variable gets created in the current thread's "memory space" and there is no way that it will get accessed by any other thread (from what you've shown above).

Answer (score 1):

Since the variables used are defined/used in it's own scope there is no need for syncronize the method.

Answer (score 0):

The method should not be synchronized but you should use a final variable arg ie 
**static returnType foo(final Object arg).**

Comment: I don't see why you would suggest this

Comment: Since arg is only used for calculation, its value should not change. Using the final keyword, you just make sure that its value could not change. In the context of multi-threading, you just make sure that the calculation is accurate specially if arg can be shared.

Comment: Arg cannot be shared.  It is completely thread-local.  Changing the value of arg will not effect the object reference of what was passed in.